# re-establishing of media link in azure live video analytics

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-iot-edge

I am working on azure live video analytics module where I need to store the video based on event , so I followed document where signal gate node used in graph topology. Its stored video whenever signal gate node get triggered.

I have implemented the same way, trigger the gate processor node to record video and using rtsp simulator with input of some 8 min video.
I have issue that after 30-40 second, media established link with rtsp server(rtsp simulator), input video started over again and this is happening repeatedly.

what could be reason ?
how can i resolved this one ..?

Answer (score 0):

The Live Video Analytics module was designed to process live video 24x7. When the RTSP simulator reaches the end of the file, it disconnects the RTSP session with the LVA module, which interprets this as a temporary glitch. LVA attempts to reconnect to the simulator which then restarts the stream.

Is your goal to try a PoC with the 8min video, and then deploy to production with cameras? Or is your requirement to process files?

Currently, the only workaround that is possible is for you to detect the first MediaSessionEstablished event, then count wall clock time to the duration of the video (eg. 8 minutes) and then de-activate the graph instance.

Comment: Sorry for delay in response.
I have observation that you can not used two same sink node for recording.
One for event based recording and other one for continues recording.

Comment: Correct - there can be only one sink node in a topology. This limitation also applies to the new release of this product: Azure Video Analyzer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-docs/overview).